# It is not showing ColumnName in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

Hello friends this is my program everything is working cool. 
But I am not able to display the column names at the top of JTable. What changes should I make to show it? And also tell me how to give scroll bars(both vertical,horizontal) to this table.

Thanks in advance..

Report1.Java:

```
package com.ash;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.naming.spi.DirStateFactory.Result;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRootPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.JTableHeader;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JTable;
    public class Report1 extends JFrame {

Object[][] data = null;


private JPanel contentPane;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
ResultSet rs,rs1;
Statement stmt=null;
int k=0;
PreparedStatement pr;
public JTable table;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Report1 frame = new Report1();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public Report1() {
    setTitle("Report");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 953, 616);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    table = new JTable();
    table.setBounds(100, 136, 810, 431);
    contentPane.add(table);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Add");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {




            try {
                NewPatient.con=DbConnPa.getConObj();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String sql="SELECT COUNT (*) FROM newpatient1";
            try {
                pr=NewPatient.con.prepareStatement(sql);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                rs=pr.executeQuery(sql);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                rs.next();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            int count = 0;
            try {
                count = rs.getInt(1);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(count);


            data= new Object [count][6];


            try {
                stmt=NewPatient.con.createStatement();
            } catch (SQLException e2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }

            String sql1="SELECT * FROM newpatient1";

            Object[] columns={"FirstName","LastName","Age","RefDoctor","Sex","RegId"};

            try {
                rs1=stmt.executeQuery(sql1);
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {


                    while(rs1.next()){

                        for(int j=0;j<6;j++){
                            try {
                                data[k][j]=rs1.getString(j+1);
                                System.out.println("i="+"j="+j);
                            } catch (SQLException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    k++;}
                }

             catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



            table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(data, columns));



        }
    });
    btnNewButton.setBounds(382, 47, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnNewButton);


}
   }
```

Answer (score 4):

Lets start with all the things that freak me out...

```
// This will come back and haunt you...
contentPane.setLayout(null);

table = new JTable();
// You should leave this up to the layout manager, but you're not using one, so...
table.setBounds(100, 136, 810, 431);
```

And now the problem...

Tables are expected to be larger then the available viewable area doing this...

```
contentPane.add(table);
```

Isn't how it's suppose to work.

You're expected to use a `JScrollPane`.  This provides the area for the header to be displayed...

[image]

```
contentPane.add(new JScrollPane(table));
```

Check out [How to use tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and [How to use scroll panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)

Eventually, you're going to want to become familiar with [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/), as reading results from the database could potentially be a long running task, causing your application to stall

**Update with example**

I also went through you data retrial code and "cleaned it up", it was rather...interesting

```
public Report1() {
    setTitle("Report");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 953, 616);
    ((JComponent) getContentPane()).setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

    table = new JTable();
    add(new JScrollPane(table));

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Add");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            PreparedStatement pr = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            Statement stmt = null;
            try {
                NewPatient.con = DbConnPa.getConObj();
                String sql = "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM newpatient1";
                pr = NewPatient.con.prepareStatement(sql);
                rs = pr.executeQuery(sql);
                if (rs.next()) {
                    int count = 0;
                    count = rs.getInt(1);
                    System.out.println(count);
                    rs.close();

                    data = new Object[count][6];

                    stmt = NewPatient.con.createStatement();

                    String sql1 = "SELECT * FROM newpatient1";

                    Object[] columns = {"FirstName", "LastName", "Age", "RefDoctor", "Sex", "RegId"};

                    rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql1);

                    while (rs.next()) {

                        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
                            data[k][j] = rs1.getString(j + 1);
                            System.out.println("i=" + "j=" + j);
                        }
                        k++;
                    }
                }

                table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(data, columns));
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    rs.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                try {
                    pr.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                try {
                    stmt.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }

        }
    });
    add(btnNewButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}
```

Comment: contentPane.setLayout(null);
table = new JTable();
table.setBounds(100, 136, 810, 431);

This code lines are auto generated from Drag and Drop plugin of eclipse.
I gone through that tutorial but still not working for me.

Suggest me the changes so It will show me Column Names

Comment: Where should I add the code line contentPane.add(new JScrollPane(table)); ?

Comment: I mean to say I have searched for this things before posting the question. When I was unable to understand I posted here.

Comment: I'll take your word for it, so many people post questions, you over tutorials and 30 seconds later they still don't understand :P

Comment: I am here to get help if you know post answer.

Comment: `I also went through you data retrial code and "cleaned it up", it was rather...interesting` == `setBounds(100, 100, 953, 616);` :-)

Comment: Thanks alot @MadProgrammer.
It worked. But please if you have time can you tell me where was my mistake?

and sorry to be rude..

Comment: @ash No worries ;) ... You're biggest mistake was not adding the `JTable` into a `JScrollPane`.  There's a little bit of magic that happens here and the header is added into the scroll pane automatically for you.  The second mistake was not using an appropriate layout manager. It's worth while your time learning how to put UI's together by hand to start with, it gives you an appreciation for how things work, form editors have there place, but really not while you're learning.

Comment: @ash Your data retrival code was using to may `try-catch` elements, meaning that any part could have failed and you would have still been trying to rely on its (errored) state

Comment: Okie boss. Thnks alot. Then instead of try-catch what should I use?

Comment: You should still use a try-catch, just not around each call. Have a look at the example, I only use one. Either the entire transaction will work or it won't

Comment: @MadProgrammer any idea about this question:

[jar file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16221427/how-to-create-jar-file-with-database-tables-oracle-jdk1-6-which-also-establishe/16230345?noredirect=1#16230345)

Comment: @MadProgrammer One more question... How to store "(double quote) into string like String a=" "T1" "

Comment: @MadProgrammer Please help me to solve this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16263975/jtable-is-not-becoming-visible    but dont change much in code.